# Out of stack space vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

and I am unable to resolve this error.. I have tried searching online but can't seem to find the solution required for this problem. It shows an "Out of stack" error(Run time error '28'). Can someone please help?

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Sheets
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer


Public Function test1(i, j)

Set ws = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
 With Application.WorksheetFunction

  test1(i, j) = .Index(ws(2).Range("B2:D5"), .Match(ws(1).Range("A" & i), ws(2).Range("A2:A5"), 0), .Match(ws(1).Range("B" & j), ws(2).Range("B1:D1"), 0))

 End With

End Function

Sub Xecute()
Set ws = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
 For i = 5 To 13 Step 4
   For j = 5 To 16

    test1(i, j) = ws(1).Range("C" & j).Value

   Next j

 Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a value to the function? i.e. `test1(i, j ) = ...`?

Comment: Hey yeah I just found that out, as I said I am new to VBA.. I rectified that error. It's working now :) But I have a new problem now, I think there is a problem with my loop in the Sub Xecute(). As the range("C" & j).value is getting filled by values corresponding to i = 13. What I am trying to do is that (C4:C8) should correspond to i = 5, (C8:C12) to i = 9 and so on.. Can you help ?

Comment: Can you post your answer?

Answer (score 1):

My corrected code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Sheets
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, p As Integer, q As Integer


Public Function test1(i, j)

Set ws = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
With Application.WorksheetFunction

 test1 = .Index(ws(2).Range("B2:D5"), .Match(ws(1).Range("A" & i), ws(2).Range("A2:A5"), 0), .Match(ws(1).Range("B" & j), ws(2).Range("B1:D1"), 0))

End With

End Function

Sub Xecute()
Set ws = Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2"))
 For i = 5 To 13 Step 4
  For j = 5 To 16

   ws(1).Range("C" & j).Value = test1(i, j)


  Next j
 Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

"Out of stack" error are caused when you assign the variable with large number more than it can hold. for example, `i and J are decalred as integer`, however the value it hold might be greated than some 32000 or more. so try declaring the variable as `double or variant`.